# Laravel - Is there a Global Variable?

Tags: php, oop, laravel

I am using Laravel. I have referenced my project name in several different places in my views.

I then decided to change the name of my application! So is there a global variable I can use instead and then I only have to change the name in one place next time?

I looked through the docs but couldn't see this feature..

Comment: Set something in the configuration files

Comment: No you cannot do that

Comment: You better read about templates in laravel http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/templates

Comment: Thanks to whoever downvoted a perfectly valid question. Cheers. Worth it. I could only think to describe my problem as Global Variable. Should I have explicitly stated that I would use any valid method for solving this? Bravo.. Seriously..

Comment: @mike3875 Don't worry too much about one downvote. It may be not the best question ever, but it's perfectly valid and I can imagine it helping a few other people searching for something similar without knowing of the config possibilities Laravel offers :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course global variables *exist* in Laravel as well. However just because the exist it doesn't mean you should use them.

A much more suitable approach would be to store the name in a config file.

You can use `app/config/app.php` and just add a row:

```
return array(
    'name' => 'FooBar',
    // existing values ...
    'debug' => false,
    'url' => 'http://localhost',
    // etc ...
);
```

Or create your very own config file. For example `app/config/site.php`

```
return array(
    'name' => 'FooBar'
);
```

And you use it like this:

```
Config::get('app.name');
```

Or

```
Config::get('site.name');
```

See [the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/configuration) for more information

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of View Composers
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#view-composers